# for loop parse newline then equal sign and put it in dictionary

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, parsing, for-loop, nsdictionary

```
NSString *result
```

result contains:

```
NC_AllowedWebHosts=
NC_BgeLAN=br1
NC_Doc=/tmp/dhd=
NC_ExPts=1863==
NC_Redirect=1
[...]
binary_custom=/path/to/directory
blocklist=0
blocklist_url=http://list.g.com/?list=
[...]
```

I am using this function but i have problems parsing list with double == or triple === for example.

```
NSArray *strings = [result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                    [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"=\r\n"]];
NSMutableArray *keys = [NSMutableArray new];
NSMutableArray *values = [NSMutableArray new];

for (int i = 0; i+1 < strings.count; i+=2) {
        [keys addObject:strings[i]];
        [values addObject:strings[i+1]];
}
```

I would like to parse everything based on new line "\r\n" first then everything that is before the *first* "=" symbol put in a dictionary key, and everything after *up to* the new line in a dictionary value. This way I can say get me key "NC_ExPts" and value would return "1863==" and so on. Any help would be appreciated.

@Monolo I can read line-by-line but I don't know how to get values on the first appearance of "=" and put it in values and keys

```
    NSArray *lines = [result componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:
                      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r\n\n"]];

    for (NSString* line in lines) {
        if (line.length) {
            NSLog(@"line: %@", line);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the original text line-by-line, then divide each line by only the *first* "="-sign. With the method you are using, you divide lines and key-value pairs in one go, meaning that you lose too much information about the structure of the data. This is why you are having difficulties handling lines with "==" in them in the value part.

`NSString`'s `enumerateLinesUsingBlock:` will take care of the first part, and finding the first "=" in each of those lines is easily done with `rangeOfString:`.

Comment: I can read line-by-line ok but not sure how to find the first '=' and parse it with key and value then.

Comment: @Squirrel There are many ways to do it. `rangeOfString:` with `@"="` as the parameter will give you the position of the first occurrence of the string, which is what you are after. Then `substringToIndex:` and `substringFromIndex:` can be used to give you key and value, respectively. The documentation of NSString is very useful: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: thanks for that tip. I am able to parse it with rangeOfString and substringToInder but now I am back to having problems reading line by line. characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\r\n\n"]] doesn't seem to work very well since I miss the beginning of the list. I don't understant why that is happening. I also tried using NSScanner but same result.